# What should I do if someone put a lot of work into answering my question - but I left out important information?

Tags: support

Someone put a lot of work into answering my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173612/how-do-i-stop-datagridview-in-winforms-automatically-generating-columns-at-desig) . Then I discovered that the behaviour only occurred when I was using a BindingNavigator and I had neglected to mention this in my question.  Is there some way I can send points for the effort?

Comment: Have you upvoted the answer yet?

Comment: Ah! I have now.

Comment: 10 points to Gryffindor... I mean, to spajce ;)

Comment: Great! Can you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens a lot

Leave a comment on their answer and wait for them to edit.

If you want to reward them for their time and their answer seems merit-able, than you can upvote the answer at your own discretion.

---

If it doesn't actually answer your question, than you shouldn't mark it as the answer.

The primary purpose of answers getting marked is for the benefit of future visitors whom will also be looking for answers to the question you've posted, and the get the most benefit if the marked answer is actually the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a bounty on your question if you feel they went way beyond your expectations in answering your question. Offering a bounty takes away a chosen amount your reputation and awards it to the person of your choice. An overview of the rules regarding bounties can be found [here.](http://www.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties)